# Error in loading data from google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

In the model I want to launch, I have some variables which have to be initialized with specific values.

I currently store these variables into numpy arrays but I don't know how to adapt my code to make it work on a google-cloud-cnn job.

Currently I initialize my variable like this:

```
f =file_io.read_file_to_string('gs://cnnfish/train_data200back.npy')
my_variable = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.load(f), name='my_variable')
```

```css
InvalidArgumentError: Error executing an HTTP request (HTTP response code 400, error code 0, error message ''), response '{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Bucket is requester pays bucket but no user project provided."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bucket is requester pays bucket but no user project provided."
 }
}
'
  when reading metadata of gs://cnnfish/train_data200back.npy
```

Answer (score 1):

The file you're attempting to read is a [Requester Pays](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/requester-pays) resource, meaning you need to meet certain access requirements:

> ... Once enabled, only the following users can access the bucket or its
>   contents:
>
> - Requesters who [include a billing project in their request](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-requester-pays#using). The project used in the request must be in good standing, and the user
>     must [have a role](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#project-add) in the project that contains the
>     `serviceusage.services.use` permission. The `roles/editor`, and
>     `roles/owner` roles contain the required permission.
> - Requesters who don't include a billing project but have `resourcemanager.projects.createBillingAssignment` permission for the
>     project that contains the bucket. The `roles/owner` project role
>     contains the required permission. Access charges associated with these
>     requests are billed to the project that contains the bucket.
>
> All other requests to the bucket fail with a `400 UserProjectMissing`
>   error.

Most likely you'll aim to be in the first bullet position. Unfortunately `file_io.read_file_to_string` does not allow you to specify a GCP project.

I can only suggest following the python code sample from [Accessing Requester Pays buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-requester-pays#using) to first download the file to your local filesystem (while specifying the project) and after that call `file_io.read_file_to_string` on that downloaded file.